# C Pointer argument mismatch compilation warning

Tags: c, pointers, avr

quick question from a very rusty C wanna be programmer. I have the following scenario

> avr-gcc -Wall -Os -DF_CPU=8000000 -mmcu=atmega328p -c mirf.c -o mirf.o
>   mirf.c: In function ‘mirf_config’: mirf.c:76:20: warning: passing
>   argument 1 of ‘mirf_set_TADDR’ from incompatible pointer type
>        mirf_set_TADDR(&addr);
>                       ^ In file included from mirf.c:27:0: mirf.h:52:13: note: expected ‘uint8_t *’ but argument is of type ‘uint8_t (*)[5]’ 
>   extern void mirf_set_TADDR(uint8_t * adr);

```
void mirf_config() 
// Sets the important registers in the MiRF module and powers the module
// in receiving mode
{

uint8 addr[5] = {0xA0,0xA1,0xA2,0xA3,0xA4};       
mirf_set_TADDR(&addr); // HERE!!

// Set RF channel
mirf_config_register(RF_CH,mirf_CH);

// Set length of incoming payload 
mirf_config_register(RX_PW_P0, mirf_PAYLOAD);

// Start receiver 
PTX = 0;        // Start in receiving mode
RX_POWERUP;     // Power up in receiving mode
mirf_CE_hi;     // Listening for pakets

}

void mirf_set_TADDR(uint8_t * adr)
// Sets the transmitting address
{
    mirf_write_register(TX_ADDR, adr,5);
}
```

How do I get rid of the warning and properly send the pointer to the 5 bytes?

thanks!!

Comment: just fixed the unknown type name, was missing the _t. but 

mirf.c:76:20: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘mirf_set_TADDR’ from incompatible pointer type
     mirf_set_TADDR(&addr);
                    ^
In file included from mirf.c:27:0:
mirf.h:52:13: note: expected ‘uint8_t *’ but argument is of type ‘uint8_t (*)[5]’
 extern void mirf_set_TADDR(uint8_t * adr);

continues

Comment: In the text above you have the type `uint8` for the array and `uint8_t` (with `_t`) for the param. Is this typo only here or in program too?

Comment: Please learn about formatting in StackOverflow. An important information is missing: the `uint8_t *` instead of the `uint8_t`, and `(*)` instead `()` in your error message quote. It is only visible by the fact that we see *italic text* between the two missing `*`. It took me some brain to spot that the compiler was not talking about function pointers.

Comment: fixed formating, sorry about that, not really used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to know is right here:

> mirf.h:52:13: note: expected ‘uint8_t ’ but argument is of type ‘int
>   ()[5]’ extern void mirf_set_TADDR(uint8_t * adr);

The `mirf_set_TADDR` function is expecting a pointer to a `uint8_t` (i.e. a `uint8_t *`) but you're passing it the address of an array (i.e. a `uint8_t (*)[5]`).  An array decays to the address of the first element when passed to a function, so get rid of the address-of operator:

```
mirf_set_TADDR(addr);
```

Comment: thanks! that was what i needed. 

    mirf_set_TADDR(&addr[0]);

Hope it works, debugging AVR is a pain!!